# Mingw undefined reference to libws2_32 ('getnameinfo', 'getaddrinfo', ...)

Tags: c, mingw, winsock

I'm trying to build my application that includes libcurl+openssl+zlib (all built from sources). It gives me the following linking error:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -DWINVER=0x0501 -DCURL_STATICLIB "-ID:\\PROJEKTY\\PC\\libcurl_openssl_zlib\\src\\lib" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\main.o" "..\\src\\main.cpp" 
g++ "-LD:\\PROJEKTY\\PC\\libcurl_openssl_zlib\\src\\lib\\curl" "-LD:\\PROJEKTY\\PC\\libcurl_openssl_zlib\\src\\lib\\openssl" "-LD:\\PROJEKTY\\PC\\libcurl_openssl_zlib\\src\\lib\\zlib" -v -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o libcurl_openssl_zlib.exe "src\\main.o" -lcurl -lcurldll -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lwldap32 -lws2_32 
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-5.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls : (reconfigured) ../src/gcc-5.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC) 
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-LD:\PROJEKTY\PC\libcurl_openssl_zlib\src\lib\curl' '-LD:\PROJEKTY\PC\libcurl_openssl_zlib\src\lib\openssl' '-LD:\PROJEKTY\PC\libcurl_openssl_zlib\src\lib\zlib' '-v' '-static-libgcc' '-o' 'libcurl_openssl_zlib.exe' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/collect2.exe -plugin c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/liblto_plugin-0.dll -plugin-opt=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\Users\Jacek\AppData\Local\Temp\cchJKgec.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -Bdynamic -o libcurl_openssl_zlib.exe c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../crt2.o c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/crtbegin.o -LD:\PROJEKTY\PC\libcurl_openssl_zlib\src\lib\curl -LD:\PROJEKTY\PC\libcurl_openssl_zlib\src\lib\openssl -LD:\PROJEKTY\PC\libcurl_openssl_zlib\src\lib\zlib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../.. src\main.o -lcurl -lcurldll -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lwldap32 -lws2_32 -Bstatic -lstdc++ -Bdynamic -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/crtend.o
D:\PROJEKTY\PC\libcurl_openssl_zlib\src\lib\openssl/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0xaa): undefined reference to `getnameinfo'
D:\PROJEKTY\PC\libcurl_openssl_zlib\src\lib\openssl/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0xb48): undefined reference to `getaddrinfo'
D:\PROJEKTY\PC\libcurl_openssl_zlib\src\lib\openssl/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0xca0): undefined reference to `getaddrinfo'
D:\PROJEKTY\PC\libcurl_openssl_zlib\src\lib\openssl/libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0x819): undefined reference to `freeaddrinfo'
D:\PROJEKTY\PC\libcurl_openssl_zlib\src\lib\openssl/libcrypto.a(init.o):init.c:(.text+0x212): undefined reference to `GetModuleHandleEx'
D:\PROJEKTY\PC\libcurl_openssl_zlib\src\lib\openssl/libcrypto.a(init.o):init.c:(.text+0x984): undefined reference to `GetModuleHandleEx'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As seen above, `-lws2_32` is put after `-lcrypto`, which means it shouldn't be an issue with linking order. "Just in case", I also did `-DWINVER=0x0501` as suggested in simiar threads with no result, even though I don't see how this would affect errors durking linking anyway (instead, it would either throw an error or a warning about implicit declaration during compilation).

I threw in verbose flag to linker to see library search paths and they're correct. Going to where libws2_32.a is located and running `nm` on it returns the following:

```
MSYS /c/MinGW/lib
$ nm.exe -g libws2_32.a | grep getnameinfo
00000000 I __imp__getnameinfo@28
00000000 T _getnameinfo@28
```

which looks like the function in question is there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have with your `libws2_32.a` is not a real static library but an *import library*. This is just a stub on windows needed for dynamic linking against the dll at runtime.

To use it, you must bind against the symbols prefixed with `__imp__` (instead of just `_`). This is what `__declspec(dllimport)` does for you. So, somehow, this was missing on the ws2_32 prototypes when compiling your `openssl` (it expects to be linked against a normal static library now).

Comment: This was indeed an issue. For some reason OpenSSL "Configure mingw [...]" does not add the `WINVER=XXX`-like defines, which in turn are checked in `ws2tcpip.h` that only defines `freeaddrinfo`, `getaddrinfo` and `getnameinfo` if `_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0501`. Therefore after running `perl Configure mingw [...]` I've added `-DWINVER=0x0501 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501` to CFLAGS in Makefile to ensure those functions are defined. Rebuilding OpenSSL with this change fixed the issue.